# Not able to see login and signup option in Jenkins home page

Tags: jenkins

I am not able to see login and signup option in Jenkins home page,was able to see those option every time but all of a sudden this is missing and every time anyone runs any build it shows as anonymous triggered the build , I want to stop this

This is how my screen top view looks

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did change with Jenkins that this behaviour suddenly appears? Did you upgrade? Installed a plugin? Did you check logging?

Comment: Hello. you need to activate security first in adminstration settings.

Comment: I have not updated anything , how to activate security ? and am scared to do so as it may block me from running any job

Comment: enabling security solved the issue thanks alot